# Microsoft Access Getting data from other table

Tags: database, ms-access

I am working on a db using microsoft access, i am using a calculated field to calculate a result, one of the input for the result is found in another table. I am not allowed to use the lookup and relationship, what should i do do get this data

Comment: If you can't use DLookup, and the tables are related but you can't use that link, I would suggest you create some VBA code to search the target table for a match using whatever key or info you have. Or you could create a form, add the other table, put a custom filter in place and search for a match.

Comment: I have used a query to solve this issue and it works the why i wanted it to